# Asus SATA drivers for Win XP repair

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, sata

I need to run a repair install on Windows XP on a Seagate SATA drive. It's plugged into an ASUS motherboard. The repair doesn't recognize the partition (unknown) and from what I understand, that's because I need to load the SATA drivers before I proceed.

1. Can anyone confirm this?
2. Where can I get these drivers? I don't quite know what I'm looking for.
3. How do I do it? Do I load it on a CD or something?

Comment: If you did not have the proper Sata driver, setup would not see the hard drive at all. Unknown partition is a sign of another more serious problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, like it sounds in your case - You will need to load SATA drivers during a repair / install. When the XP disc is loading - It will say something similar to 'Press F6 to load SATA drivers' - This will begin a search on the floppy drive.

If you download the drivers for your motherboard, you should be able to find them from asus support site, extract them onto a floppy disc and your good to go.

Comment: don't have a floppy disc drive. If i burn the drivers to a CD-rom will that work? And do I just get the standard SATA drivers for my moterboard?

Comment: A CD might work - As long as you have two drives. Your XP CD is in one - Might be able to take it out temporarily though. Yes standard SATA drivers should be fine.

Comment: I'm having a go with this: http://news.softpedia.com/news/Install-Windows-XP-On-SATA-Without-a-Floppy-F6-47807.shtml

Comment: nope, didn't work..

Comment: What about it didn't work? Did you get an error?

Comment: With XP, ONLY a floppy will work...It will not search anywhere else but A:\. You will need an external floppy drive to move forward.